# Replace value= '#somevalue before' with a new value

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, replace

I have an html file in which I want to replace the value of a variable inside of it, like that for example

```
name = 'x' value= '50'
```

I want to replace the value from any number to a specific number like 13,The problem is I don't know what is the current value so I need a way that python replace the current value no matter what value it is, but for sure I know it is an integer.

Comment: you need to utilize an HTML parser (I'd recommend `BeautifulSoup`). Then just locate the node in the document via xpath, and edit the value of the attribute you want.

Comment: I am sure there is a way to use the replace function that will be easier than using an HTML parser

Answer (score -1):

Make use of regular expressions. Read your html file and find all the variable occurrences in the file and replace it with the your interested value.

Comment: definitely not a regex for parsing HTML, see the traditional question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/217723